# Unable to set LC_COLLATE='C' LC_CTYPE='C' in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I tried following [this guide](https://landchad.net/dendrite/) to install a Matrix Dendrite server. I'm now at the stage of installing postgresql, but ran into an error when I tried to run

```
su -c "psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE dendrite ENCODING 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE='C' LC_CTYPE='C' template=template0 OWNER dendrite;'" postgres
```

This was the response I received:

```
declare -x HOME="/var/lib/postgresql"
declare -x LOGNAME="postgres"
declare -x MAIL="/var/mail/postgres"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
declare -x PWD="/var/lib/postgresql"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x USER="postgres"
ERROR:  invalid locale name: "c"
```

I'm confused ***why*** I wasn't able to create a databse with the locale name C? Should I try to fix it so C can be accepted, or should I try to use another locale name?

Comment: I guessing shell quoting/escaping issue. Just use [createdb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html): `createdb -p 5432 -U postgres --locale=C -O dendrite -T template0  dendrite`